In python, is there a way to use shlex to split a line but leave quotes intact?
I know there have been similar questions about shlex, but none that seem to directly address this issue.
I would like to do basically what shlex.split() does (in POSIX mode), except just split - don't remove any quotes or backslashes.  I would still like quotes and backslashes to function as they normally do (including being able to escape quotes) - I just don't want them removed.
An earlier version of my application was in perl, where Text::ParseWords is a rough equivalent of shlex.  I'm looking for the python equivalent of Text::ParseWords::quotewords with $keep=1.
For instance, I would like:
shlex.split('abc "def ghi" jkl')

to return:
[ 'abc', '"def ghi"', 'jkl' ]

I recognize that if I set posix=False, this particular example would work, but that's not a general solution because posix=False also disables escaping quotes and affects lexing in other undesirable ways.
From what I can tell in the documentation, whether I use split() or a lower-level interface to the parser, if I use posix, the quotes are stripped before I see them, but if I don't, then escapes aren't handled.
I really am doing POSIX-style shell processing (which is what leads me to shlex), but shlex goes one step too far for me - stripping quotes loses the information of how the original was quoted, which is important for shell-like processing, so I want it to stop before it does that.
If there right answer isn't shlex, is there something else that doesn't involve writing a lexer from scratch?

The real shell parsing process also destroys the information of what the original quoting was.

Yes, eventually, but it needs to know what the quoting was so it knows what sorts of expansions to do.  Also, history processing needs to split on words but it also needs to keep the quoting intact.  For instance, in bash:
% echo abc 'def ghi' jkl
% !:2:p
'def ghi'

What you really want there is character-by-character analysis of how each piece of the command is quoted. That's a thing worth building, but it's also a lot more code.

I agree that to fully interpret the line, I need the character-by-character analysis.  There are some pieces of it like history expansion, however, that require word-splitting but not the full-blown analysis.  I was hoping to leverage shlex for that.
